# Unable to dispatch method insert in CBQLink

Tags: ns2

I was trying to make a CBQ between two nodes and I keep getting the error "Unable to dispatch method insert" for the line:

```
$cbqlink insert $class1
```

According to the documentation CBQLink has the method `insert`: http://www-sop.inria.fr/planete/software/ns-doc/ns-current/CBQLink.html

Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found out what's wrong.

I was creating a CBQ on a `duplex-link` and this caused all the issues. I changed it to `simplex-link` and everything worked fine!

Comment: It seems that if you create a CBQ on both side it could work